# How to create a list of different types in Graph QL

Tags: graph-databases, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and I am trying to figure out the best practices behind Schema design. Designing Schemas and Connections for GraphQL feels a little bit like designing a relational database, but I'm not sure of all of the best practices. In GraphQL how would you implement the following solution:

#### Let's say you have a list of vehicles:

```
1. Honda Accord
2. Ford Focus
3. Ducati Monster
4. Cessna 152
5. Santa Cruz Nomad
```

#### Each of these vehicles is of a different type:

```
1. Honda Accord (car)
2. Ford Focus (car)
3. Ducati Monster (motorcycle)
4. Cessna 152 (airplane)
5. Santa Cruz Nomad (bicycle)
```

#### You already have Schemas for each type

There is already a schema and a resolver for each type of vehicle that implemented the same interface (id, make, model):

```
 Car {
    id,
    make
    model
    ...
 }

 MotorCycle {
    id
    make
    model
    ...
 }

 AirPlane {
    id,
    make
    model
    ...
 }

 Bicycle {
    id
    make
    model
    ...
 }
```

#### How would you implement the garage?

What is the best way to create a Garage Type that can be used to access a list of different vehicle types that may be found in a garage even though each vehicle has it's own schema?

I'm not sure if this is possible, or how to implement this correctly, but what I am trying to do is something like:

```
{
    garage(id: "cGVvcGx10jE=") {
        location
        vehicleConnection {
            edges {
                node {
                    make
                    model
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
 {
     "data": {
       "garage": {
         "location": "Sunnyvale",
         "vehicleConection": {
             "edges": [
               {
                 "node": {
                     "make": "Honda",
                     "model": "Accord"
                 }
               },
               {
                 "node": {
                     "make": "Ford",
                     "model": "Focus"
                 }
               },                         {
                 "node": {
                     "make": "Ducati",
                     "model": "Monster"
                 }
               },
               {
                 "node": {
                     "make": "Cessna",
                     "model": "152"
                 }
               },
               {
                 "node": {
                     "make": "Santa Cruz",
                     "model": "Nomad"
                 }
               }             
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use inheratence.

```
interface Vehicle {
    id: ID!,
    make: String,
    model: String
}

type Car implements Vehicle {
    ...
}

type MotoCycle implements Vehicle {
    ...
}

// and now you can connect Garage to Vehicle
```

See http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces

Ot the other possibility: Union type http://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types

They are largely the same, but as union doesn't expect some common properties between objects, the saved structure is larger.

Comment: I already created the Vehicle Interface... it's UNION TYPES... that is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!